# what languages would be required to import a csv file and display the data in a bootstrap website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a csv file containing data I want to report on, and I'm trying to work out what the workflow would be in terms of what programming languages I would need to implement the following scenario:

scenario first then (language) in brackets.

As an example; data extracted in step 2 might be count of number of records in a particular category: clothing!

I am not too sure of the languages but I think the workflow would need to be:

1. press button on bootstrap website, brings up file manager: pick file 2 import (javascript) - javascript calls python script in step 2
2. upon pressing ok and importing a file, the file would be opened/manipulated using (python) - results passed back from python to the website dashboard using javascript?
3. use either (html 5) and or (javascript) and or a visualisation language like d3 to pass the manipulated data to one of the bootstrap admin dashboards below, and display the number of sales of clothing in my report:

[bootstrap admin dashboards](http://www.bearfruit.org/2014/09/17/free-or-cheap-html-admin-dashboard-themes/%22bootstrapadmindashboards%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the browser with Javascript.

You can catch the *change* event with a listener on the upload button, then use in the callback the FileReader api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

No need to send the file to your python server.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" />
```

Javascript:

```
var readCSV = function (event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        var lines = theFile.target.result.split(/\n|\r/);
        //code here
    }
}

document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener('change', readCSV);
```

Comment: Samuel, so are you saying the data manipulation (counting the number of sales of category-clothing) can all be done in the browser with Javascript? and python is not needed at all? Is javascript slow when compared to python? (have only used python briefly).

Comment: Don't compare Javascript and Python, but try to estimate how long you will transmit the file throw the network. If your file is very very too big, the browser could crash. You should make test to be sure.

Comment: Samuel, so python doesn't need to be used at all to achieve the workflow I described above? If I did want to use python (to do the data analysis and queries) is there a way of calling python from javascript, and then using javascript to store the results from the python script directly in the dashboard? - I'm struggling to find any tutorials /resources which show how to modify the admin panel/ dashboards and how to make it show actual information (like number of sales of a specific clothing item)?